# Reinstall mysql-server after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 - errors

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04

Mysql needed to be reinstalled after I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.  I did 'sudo service mysqld stop' before the upgrade, and then the cleanup step must have removed mysql server.  When it wasn't found I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server
sudo apt-get install mysql-server

...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
mysqld: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored.
Please enable --log-error option or set appropriate redirections for standard output and/or standard error in daemon mode.
Warning: Unable to start the server. Please restart MySQL and run mysql_upgrade to ensure the database is ready for use.
mysqld: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored.
Please enable --log-error option or set appropriate redirections for standard output and/or standard error in daemon mode.
Warning: Unable to start the server.
...
```

I then ran 'systemctl status mysql.service' which reported this:

```
Jul 19 11:21:49 steve-VAIO mysqld[6106]: 2018-07-19T18:21:49.828124Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file oper
Jul 19 11:21:49 steve-VAIO mysqld[6106]: 2018-07-19T18:21:49.828132Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the pat
Jul 19 11:21:49 steve-VAIO mysqld[6106]: 2018-07-19T18:21:49.828140Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for `my
Jul 19 11:21:49 steve-VAIO mysqld[6106]: 2018-07-19T18:21:49.828199Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot calculate statistics for table `mysql
Jul 19 11:21:49 steve-VAIO mysqld[6106]: 2018-07-19T18:21:49.828232Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Tablespace is mi
Jul 19 11:21:49 steve-VAIO mysqld[6106]: 2018-07-19T18:21:49.846964Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180719 11:21:4
Jul 19 11:21:49 steve-VAIO mysqld[6106]: 2018-07-19T18:21:49.934673Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
Jul 19 11:21:49 steve-VAIO mysqld[6106]: 2018-07-19T18:21:49.934950Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Jul 19 11:21:49 steve-VAIO mysqld[6106]: Version: '5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu
Jul 19 11:21:49 steve-VAIO systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

mysqld is running and my databases are available, but I'm sure this will bite me again when it updates.  phpMyAdmin shows the mysql database, which seems healthy.  At the top of the list of databases is one called '#mysql50#mysql.bkp'.

Any suggestions for cleaning this up?

After suggestion to run mysql_upgrade, I did:

```
steve@steve-VAIO:~/workspace/JavascriptCourse$ mysql_upgrade -u root -p
mysql_upgrade: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored.
Enter password: 
Checking if update is needed.
Checking server version.
Running queries to upgrade MySQL server.
mysql_upgrade: [ERROR] 1812: Tablespace is missing for table `mysql`.`plugin`.
```

So I'll hunt for a fix for this table's tablespace.

Comment: Did you upgrade mysql server also? Have you missed this step https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-upgrade.html ?

Comment: You might want to look at that warning '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' and change permissions of config file. Also logs you have posted are truncated.

Comment: I'll backup, do a mysql purge and reinstall again.  I was hoping to avoid wiping it all out as I have a lot of data in some of my databases.

Comment: Changing permissions did clear it up.